# How to iterate through a sub-category within rxjs filter operator

Tags: angular, database, typescript, api, rxjs

I have implemented a sorting function in my ionic app which receives information from an API. The database contains information about individual vouchers. The structure is as shown below:
[image: database structure]

To filter the results of these vouchers, I want to use the 'name' sub category under get_categories and its respective index number (as support for multiple categories are required) - in this case "Tester". I am using the filter rxjs operator to filter results.

```
    this.filteredList = from(this.vouchers)
    .pipe(filter(item => item.get_categories.?? === this.category),toArray())
```

How can I access the category name from within the filter operator in order to compare it with the selected category?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter like this.

```
this.filteredList = from(this.vouchers)
    .pipe(filter(item => item.get_categories.filter(x => x.name === this.category)),toArray())
```

but you should be careful that **get_categories** would not be null.

Comment: I tried this but when I try to sort it does not do anything (no vouchers are hidden). I know the filtering does work as when I try it with something simple like `filter(item => item.name === this.category)` it does filter correctly, so it appears that the second filter function in this solution is always passing for some reason.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a3qxck?file=pages%2Ftabs%2Ftab1.ts 
I have replaced the actual API link for security purposes.

Comment: StackBlitz has error. **Import error, can't find file:
../pages/tabs/tabs**  :|

Comment: I can't seem to get stackblitz to display anything without an error when pasting just the html/ts for this specific page. Should I try just uploading the whole project? Even then it will not be fully functional without the API. Is there any potential reasons you can think of as to why this would not be working otherwise? I am not getting any errors or warning in the console.

Comment: Do you mean that you get the filter result but sort is not working, right ?

Comment: I get the vouchers displaying, but the sort does not remove any irrelevant vouchers. (This is when I try the two filter functions)

Comment: The same behaviour that I am experiencing can be seen here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-eyvvfu?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100
While I am trying to filter only the index 0 numbers, it logs the whole array of each index, even though it does not match the modulus condition.

Comment: @Baguette I can help you only if I can see your real code. upload some mock data instead of API in stack blitz.

Comment: I tried to upload my full code but it still does not display. I am getting the following error: "Error: core_1.defineInjectable is not a function". I looked online and apparently this is due to the angular on stackblitz being an older version than what I am using. Is there any way to fix this?